# Connect to file share on an Airport Extreme from iPad/iPhone 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to connect to a hard drive or thumb drive that is plugged into an Airport Extreme.  I assume you connect to it by using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I don't know how to format the url.

I can access it from the mac by connecting to the server smb://serveraddress.local etc... and entering user/pwd.  I need to be able to access this using the iPad and stream video from it and open files.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: I've tried to format an nsurl from this string... smb://AirportEx.local/HP USB FD/videofile.mp4...I've also tried to format it multiple ways using file://...and pass it to a request then to a connection and I get back bad URL error every time.  I just need to know how to format it or if there is another way and I'm way off base.  I know how to send requests to webservers, but I can't get this to work.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect AFP or SMB shared volumes, NSURLConnection can not help you.

Since there is no any SDK for you, you need to write your own AFP or SMB client.

Here is an Open Source AFP client: [afpfs-ng](http://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home)

but I don't think you can run it on iPhone as easy as copy&past.

Comment: Is this the only solution?  What I want to do is access video from a HD or thumb drive attached to an Airport Extreme and play it.  Is there another way like AirPlay?  Any other suggestions?